# Detectar stop() do Object Embed e retorna Alert()

Tags: javascript, html, css

A todos, mais uma vez, peço ajuda.

Estou a utilizar um **firefox** com **MPlayer Plugin**

O quê quero é emitir um alert ao fim de um vídeo reproduzido, ou seja, se o reprodutor de vídeos esta inativo(parado) emitir `alert()` ou se tiver ativo(rodando) a função continua verificando com *método* `setInterval()`.

O que tenho feito até agora desde o momento da pergunta formulada:

```
<script>
<!--
var obj = document.embeds[0];

function Stop(){
obj.Stop(); alert('Tempo de Preview, terminado.');
}

window.onload = function(){setTimeout('Stop()', 10*1000);}
-->
</script>
```

> Digamos que obtive um avanço, porém o que tenho no momento é um código que faz uma pré-visualização do vídeo por **10 segundos** e pronto!

Mas a intenção, é identificar se o vídeo chegou ao fim, se chegou então emitir um `alert()`, senão continua verificando se o vídeo no `<embed/>` está ou não Parado(stop).

> Este *dialog* `alert()` é só para ilustrar o exemplo do que quero.

Só que para isso, como pode-se notar, é preciso verificar de tempo em tempo pelo *método* `setInterval()`, ainda não consegui formular uma rotina que capture esta *propriedade* nativa `Stop()`

Comment: Eu tava quase entendendo, mas ai:"O quê quero é pegar o fim de um vídeo reproduzido sem saber o tempo decorrido."Isso me confundiu, dá mais alguns detalhes... Pensa na "receita do bolo", qual o passo a passo do que deseja?

Comment: Vê se te ajuda man... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_ended e http://w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: Ajudou, fluiu ou parou ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá uma olhada patrão:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    function vidplay() {
       var vid = document.getElementById("Videobox");
       var button = document.getElementById("btn_play");
       if (vid.paused) {
          vid.play();
          document.getElementById("pipoca").innerHTML = "Ae, pipoca quentinha !";
          button.textContent = "||";
          
       } else {
          vid.pause();
          document.getElementById("pipoca").innerHTML = " ";
          alert("Não para não, tava legal !");
          button.textContent = ">";
       }
    }

    function restart() {
        var vid = document.getElementById("Videobox");
        video.currentTime = 0;
    }

    function skip(value) {
        var vid = document.getElementById("Videobox");
        video.currentTime += value;
    } 
    

 function myFunction() { 
  var vid = document.getElementById("Videobox");
     alert("Acabou, gostou do vídeo ? Acesse : http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/ e veja mais !");
}      
</script>

</head>
<body>        

<video id="Videobox" onended="myFunction()" autoplay>
    <source src="http://mirror.cessen.com/blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_iphone.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
     
</video>

<div id="controles">
    <button id="btn_restart" onclick="restart();">[]</button> 
    <button id="btn_rew" onclick="skip(-10)">&lt;&lt;</button>
    <button id="btn_play" onclick="vidplay()">&gt;</button>
    <button id="btn_fastFwd" onclick="skip(10)">&gt;&gt;</button>
</div>
<p>Video <a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>
<p id="pipoca"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso possa ajudar mais alguém, acesse - [saber-se-um-video-do-youtube-terminou](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/505330-saber-se-um-video-do-youtube-terminou/)